# Problem with including .png image in Latex (overleaf): Picture not formated correctly

Tags: graphics, formatting

I have a question regarding the \includegraphics command. I have used it before, also with ".png" pictures and I have not had any problems yet (I am pretty new to Latex though). However, I just tried to include a picture in my document and the result looks like this (the picture is cut off at about half of the picture, and right aligned, which is both not intended; in addition it shows part of the filename):

[image]

Here is the code I am using. I also tried only \includegraphics, \includegraphics[width=\textwidth] etc. already:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Statistics II/Instrumentv.png}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

And here the code immediately before the figure, in case this is relevant:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $D = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 Z + v$
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Regression of D on Z, "treatment assignment model"
    \end{enumerate}
    \item $\hat{D} = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 Z$
    \item $Y = \beta_0 + \beta^{2SLS} \hat{D} + e$
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item 2SLS only retains variation of D which is caused by Z
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

I googled quite extensively now and I just cannot get to the bottom of the problem here. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Spaces in filenames or paths are sometimes problematic. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Try renaming your file to remove the space in the file name , this often causes issues. you may also want to consider using `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...}` instead of the `scale` argument

Comment: view the png file in another application such as a browser or ms paint etc, is the white space in the image?